# for loop & while loop not working in asynctask doInBackground in android?

Tags: android, for-loop, while-loop, android-asynctask, do-while

I am facing a very silly problem in my project and not able to resolve it. I am using AsyncTask for fetching current location of user. In that i used one counter to work as timer. Inside doInBackground I am incrementing that counter and if its greater than x value then i cancel the async task.

**Here is the code snippet : -**

```
class CurrentPositionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        long counter = 0;
        boolean flag = true;

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            do {
                counter++;
                if (latitude != 0 && longitude != 0) {
                    flag = false;
                }
            } while (counter <= 100000);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```

But here the while condition is not working. I also tried the for loop instead of while but that is not also working for me. Also face very strange problem, when i print the counter using sysout its working fine but without it its not working..

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This loop

```
while (counter <= 100000 || flag);
```

will go on as long as any of the conditions hold, so it will continue *while counter <= 10000 or flag is true*. If `flag` is `false` but `counter` is less than `100000` it will continue. If you intend to terminate the loop when `flag` is `false`, then you need to do instead:

```
while (counter <= 100000 && flag);
```

**Update:** It seems from your comments that you expect the hundred thousand incrementation of the `counter` variable to take roughly 20-30 seconds. Current day processors are **way** faster than that. I won't even mention the speed variation between processors, because its negligible anyway. You can wait for real 30 seconds with this loop, though is a *busy-waiting* loop (just like your original intent) and not something nice to do:

```
final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
do {
    ...
} while( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime <= 30 * 1000 );
```

Comment: but the loop is not working.I also tried your suggestion,...
what i want is to wait for 10-20 second and then i need to break the loop but loop breaks all the time and go to the onPostExecute method. Then for debugging i sysout the counter at that time its working absolutely fine..

Comment: @Scorpion: Seems that `latitude` and `longitude` are 0?

Comment: now i changed the condition and i use only counter..basically what i want is to wait for 20-30 second for getting location if not found during this duration then go to next screen...so i am using counter variable as timer...

Comment: @Scorpion: Oh! So you expect that a hundred thousand integral incrementations will take about 20-30 seconds?

Comment: I am just doing trial and error for that....i can't say exactly that 100k will take 20-30 seconds...

Comment: @Scorpion: Yes, I suggest you see my edit to the answer, suggesting a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Time bound task can be done using the TimerTask. Check the following:

```
boolean timeExpired = false;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Timer t =new Timer();

            TimerTask tk = new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    timeExpired = true;
                }
            };

            t.schedule(tk, 500);

            while(!timeExpired){
                if (latitude != 0 && longitude != 0) {
                    t.cancel();
                    tk.cancel();
                    break;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
Looper.prepare();
```

before while loop in doInBackground method